# Umbraco deletes models after adding new document type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco

Whenever I create a new document type in Umbraco and stops my server it deletes all of the generated models.

I read the documentation and it is properly because I have the following value set in my `web.config`

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="LiveAppData" />
```

Right now I am kind of stuck because I can't start my project up again without it telling me that all of the models are missing.

So my question is how can I generate the models manually? or is that something i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your Builder Mode to Dll, you can trigger a manual rebuild of the models from the Developer section in Umbraco.

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />
```